SwiftUI Sticky Notes: Incorrect Position and Frame Alignment in a Canvas-like View
I’m working on a SwiftUI project where I’m trying to implement interactive Sticky Notes that can be moved, resized, and rotated on a Canvas-like view. The Sticky Notes should also have editable text fields. However, I’ve encountered a problem where:

The position of the Sticky Notes does not align with the visible note on the screen.

When the Sticky Note is moved or resized, the interactive frame (used for context menus or gestures) doesn’t follow the note.

The rotation and scaling transformations don’t apply consistently to the text or frame.


I’ve tried debugging the issue by inspecting the frames and positions in both local and global coordinate spaces, and it seems like the global offset of the Canvas might be interfering with the Sticky Notes’ alignment.
I have my Code below:

struct StickyNoteView: View {
    @Binding var stickyNote: StickyNote
    @State private var isEditing: Bool = false
    var onDelete: () -> Void
    var onDuplicate: () -> Void

    var body: some View {
        InteractiveElementView(element: $stickyNote) {
            ZStack {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(stickyNote.color.toColor())
                SelectableTextEditor(text: $stickyNote.text, isEditing: $isEditing)
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.clear)
            }
            .highPriorityGesture(
                TapGesture(count: 2).onEnded {
                    isEditing = true
                }
            )
        }
        .contextMenu {
            Button("Löschen") {
                onDelete()
            }
            Button("Duplizieren") {
                onDuplicate()
            }
        }
    }
}

import PencilKit

struct NotesDetailView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @Environment(NotesViewModel.self) private var viewModel
    let noteIndex: Int

    @State private var canvasView = PKCanvasView()
    @State private var toolPicker = PKToolPicker()
    @State private var isShowingImagePicker = false
    @State private var isInteractingWithElement = false

    var body: some View {
        @Bindable var viewModel = viewModel

        VStack {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                ZStack {
                    CanvasRepresentable(
                        canvasView: $canvasView,
                        toolPicker: $toolPicker,
                        note: $viewModel.notes[noteIndex],
                        isInteractingWithElement: $isInteractingWithElement
                    )
                    .disabled(isInteractingWithElement) // Disable Canvas when interacting with StickyNotes
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
                    .onAppear {
                        toolPicker.addObserver(canvasView)
                        toolPicker.setVisible(true, forFirstResponder: canvasView)
                        canvasView.becomeFirstResponder()
                    }
                    .onDisappear {
                        saveDrawing()
                    }

                    // Overlay StickyNotes
                    ForEach($viewModel.notes[noteIndex].stickyNotes) { $stickyNote in
                        StickyNoteView(
                            stickyNote: $stickyNote,
                            onDelete: {
                                if let index = viewModel.notes[noteIndex].stickyNotes.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == stickyNote.id }) {
                                    viewModel.notes[noteIndex].stickyNotes.remove(at: index)
                                }
                            },
                            onDuplicate: {
                                let newStickyNote = stickyNote.duplicate()
                                viewModel.notes[noteIndex].stickyNotes.append(newStickyNote)
                            }
                        )
                    }

                    // Overlay NoteImages
                    ForEach($viewModel.notes[noteIndex].images) { $noteImage in
                        NoteImageView(
                            noteImage: $noteImage,
                            onDelete: {
                                if let index = viewModel.notes[noteIndex].images.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == noteImage.id }) {
                                    viewModel.notes[noteIndex].images.remove(at: index)
                                }
                            },
                            onDuplicate: {
                                let newImage = noteImage.duplicate()
                                viewModel.notes[noteIndex].images.append(newImage)
                            }
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        .toolbar {
            // Linker Button: Zurück zur Notizen-Übersicht + Titel
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                HStack {
                    Button(action: {
                        presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
                            .font(.title2)
                    }
                    Text(viewModel.notes[noteIndex].title)
                        .font(.headline)
                        .lineLimit(1)
                        .truncationMode(.tail)
                }
            }

            // Mittiges Menü
            ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                NotesMenu(
                    isShowingImagePicker: $isShowingImagePicker,
                    note: $viewModel.notes[noteIndex]
                )
            }

            // Rechter Button: Fertig
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                Button("Fertig") {
                    presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                }
                .font(.title2)
            }
        }
    }

    private func saveDrawing() {
        // Zeichnung speichern, wenn die Ansicht geschlossen wird
        let newDrawingData = canvasView.drawing.dataRepresentation()
        if newDrawingData != viewModel.notes[noteIndex].drawingData {
            viewModel.notes[noteIndex].drawingData = newDrawingData
        }
    }
}

import PencilKit

struct CanvasRepresentable: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var canvasView: PKCanvasView
    @Binding var toolPicker: PKToolPicker
    @Binding var note: Note
    @Binding var isInteractingWithElement: Bool

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> PKCanvasView {
        updateBackground(for: canvasView)
        canvasView.drawingPolicy = .anyInput
        canvasView.delegate = context.coordinator

        // Zeichnung laden, falls vorhanden
        if let data = note.drawingData, let drawing = try? PKDrawing(data: data) {
            canvasView.drawing = drawing
        }

        toolPicker.addObserver(canvasView)
        toolPicker.setVisible(true, forFirstResponder: canvasView)
        canvasView.becomeFirstResponder()

        return canvasView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: PKCanvasView, context: Context) {
        uiView.isUserInteractionEnabled = !isInteractingWithElement

        if let data = note.drawingData, let newDrawing = try? PKDrawing(data: data) {
            if newDrawing != uiView.drawing {
                uiView.drawing = newDrawing
            }
        }
        updateBackground(for: uiView)
    }

    private func updateBackground(for canvasView: PKCanvasView) {
        switch note.background {
        case .none:
            canvasView.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemBackground
        case .grid:
            canvasView.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: generateGridBackground())
        case .dotted:
            canvasView.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: generateDottedBackground())
        case .lined:
            canvasView.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: generateLinedBackground())
        }
    }

    // Dynamisch generierte Hintergründe
    private func generateGridBackground() -> UIImage {
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: CGSize(width: 30, height: 30))
        return renderer.image { context in
            let path = UIBezierPath()
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 15))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 30, y: 15))
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 15, y: 0))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 15, y: 30))
            UIColor.lightGray.setStroke()
            path.lineWidth = 0.5
            path.stroke()
        }
    }

    private func generateDottedBackground() -> UIImage {
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10))
        return renderer.image { context in
            let path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: 4, y: 4, width: 2, height: 2))
            UIColor.systemGray.setFill()
            path.fill()
        }
    }

    private func generateLinedBackground() -> UIImage {
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: CGSize(width: 30, height: 30))
        return renderer.image { context in
            let path = UIBezierPath()
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 15))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 30, y: 15))
            UIColor.lightGray.setStroke()
            path.lineWidth = 0.5
            path.stroke()
        }
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, PKCanvasViewDelegate {
        var parent: CanvasRepresentable

        init(_ parent: CanvasRepresentable) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        func canvasViewDrawingDidChange(_ canvasView: PKCanvasView) {
            let newDrawingData = canvasView.drawing.dataRepresentation()
            if newDrawingData != parent.note.drawingData {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.parent.note.drawingData = newDrawingData
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Any advice on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated!
